# How to Properly Encrypt JSON String in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, encryption, encryption-symmetric

This data is the hex string of encrypted json string. This is encrypted by symmetric key.

```
Key: PojmoHD0HNuE/Q+3sKD/ARj86XRYitueWmpjyCuoHuSX71xXlU0hN72wXdrWdt7w//N1BF6GQMLKZIkKXpQ8v18vP1kFG/vO3TpKZRTPhGUyFxE8y1CRIPUJesnbM+Cy3xPegQ3H2wn00YP5f2Dw0uDUHke2MEkCXHYyAgxGqo8=

Encrypted Hex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
```

I have to encrypt/decrypt JSON String in the following manner with the key. I tried different algorithms but none of them are working.
I tried the following code.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc'

const encryptData = (data, key) => {

    var mykey = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, key);

    var mystr = mykey.update(data, 'utf8', 'hex')
    mystr += mykey.final('hex');
    console.log(mystr);
    return mystr;
}

const decryptData = (encrypted, key) => {

    var mykey = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, key);
    var mystr = mykey.update(encrypted, 'hex', 'utf8')
    mystr += mykey.final('utf8');

    console.log(mystr);
    return mystr;
}
```

Comment: This key doesn't make sense. If it's a string, then it's a 172-byte key, and if it's intended to be Base64-encoded, it's a 128-byte key. AES expects a 128-*bit* (or 192-bit or 256-bit) key. This key is much too large. What code generated the "Encrypted Hex" output? Why do you believe it's aes-256-cbc? (If it's CBC, there should be an IV?) What is the plaintext?

Comment: I'm not completely aware of plaintext about that particular encrypted data but I know it will be something like that;
```
const orderData = {
    sourceType: "Web",
    merchantId: "410220816251723",
    merchantName: "Nurul",
    orderId: "1",
    amount: "600",
    transactionDate:"20190908212925",
    merchantCallBackUri: "http://localhost:8080"
}
```

Comment: Actually I got the following data from the example of the doc I was having problem with, here is what the document was telling "This data is the hex string of
encrypted json string of order data.
This is encrypted by symmetric
transaction key which is generated
(AS merchantKey) using merchantId
and orderId during RPG - Init -
Session.". The order data I added in the previous comment and the 'marchantKye' is the key in the question.

Comment: If this is a public specification that others will likely implement, then it would be helpful to point to where that is online. If this is a custom specification for a particular system or vendor, then this is likely more of a consulting question. Your current code is a long way from what you're describing, and it's likely too large and specific a question to be answered in this forum. Best of luck; you can see my profile for contact information or may want to investigate a consulting site like codementor.io.

Comment: Appreciate your help, will consult with the vendor or someone